# C++ // Converting a 1D array of chars to uppercase

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to modify a 1D array of charecters and put all of the letters contained in that array into Uppercase letters, and then print them out (and save the array with uppercase letters).

This is what I have for my function but I'm not sure what else I must do to get this working

```
void putInUppercase(char text[]) {
assert(isValidText(text)); 
int index(0);
while (text[index] != EOT)
    putchar(toupper(text));
cout << text[index];
++index;
}
```

text is the array which contains the chars.

Comment: `putchar(toupper(text))` won't modify the array

Comment: Please explain in what way(s) this is not working.

Comment: putchar(toupper(text)); on this line I get "argument of type char is incompatible with parameter of type int"

Comment: `toupper(text)` will (usually) give undefined behavior for most characters outside the US-ASCII character set (e.g., letters with accents or umlauts). You normally want to cast to unsigned first: `toupper((unsigned char)text[index])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds like you want:

```
      text[index]=toupper(text[index]);
```

instead of

otherwise you're trying to write the output twice and never updating the array

also, your while loop appears to be missing brackets.

```
void putInUppercase(char text[]) {
    assert(isValidText(text)); 
    int index(0);
    while (text[index] != EOT)
    }
        text[index]=toupper(text[index]);
        cout << text[index];
        ++index;
    }
}
```